# ECR repo access for lightsail with CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-ecr, amazon-lightsail

I'd like to create a Lightsail container with access to a private ECR repository using cdk v2.

The container creation runs fine with:

```js
const container = new lightsail.CfnContainer(this, containerServiceName, {
    serviceName: containerServiceName,
    scale: 1,
    power: 'nano',
});
```

but after that, I am not able to give the container access to the repo without using the console.

Any hint?

Thanks